# Forwarding SAML by delegation - POST from web server to web server

Tags: asp.net, saml, impersonation, delegation, ws-federation

I have an ASP.NET web app using WSFederation for user authentication. I would like to impersonate the users and make a webrequest to another web server from my web server through delegation. The other server also does WSFederation.

Ultimately, i just need a single page from the other web server. There is some header info i need from that HTTP Response Header. Sample code below.

I have been following these steps but this is for Webserver -> WCF, not Webserver -> Webserver.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adfs2-identity-delegation-step-by-step-guide(v=ws.10).aspx

Based on that article, I got the following in my web.config:

```
 <system.identityModel>
 <identityConfiguration saveBootstrapContext="true">
```

Here is a bit of sample code that I'm running to make the web request to the second webapp. Its a simple POST and I need to read some data off the Response header.

```
        try
        {
            var claimsPrincipal = ClaimsPrincipal.Current;
            if (claimsPrincipal.Identities.First().BootstrapContext == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("No bootstrap context found");
            }
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://destServer/sap/bc/gui/sap/its/webgui/?sap-client=555&sap-language=en");
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.ContentLength = data.Length;

            using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }

            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            var responseBody = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
            var responseHeaders = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < response.Headers.Count; ++i)
            {
                responseHeaders += response.Headers.Keys[i] + ": " + response.Headers[i] + " <br/>";
            }

            ViewBag.responseHeader = responseHeaders;
            ViewBag.responseBody = responseBody;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ViewBag.responseHeader = "FAILED";
            ViewBag.responseBody = e.Message;
        }
```

I'm not sure how I need to add the appropriate SAML token into the request. Right now this results in a redirect response to the STS. I know I need to work with the STS admins to get the correct tokens, but assuming I already had this, how does one POST (or GET) to another website with those SAML tokens?

Comment: Still looking for help on this. I've got some sample code added on what I'm doing.